# UPDATE doesn't affect the record at all

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update some records in my database, this code have been working previously but isn't anymore. After changing the id variable to a fixed number the code still doesn't affect the database. No error is being emitted.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx;charset=utf8', 'xxx', 'xxx');

$party = ($_POST['party']);
$id = ($_POST['id']); // $id is a string with ids separated by commas (1,2,3,4 e.t.c.)
$state = ($_POST['state']); // $state is either 1 or 0.
$code = ($_POST['fetchCode']);

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE wishes SET state = $state WHERE fetchCode = '$code' AND partyID = '$party' AND id IN ($id); ");

$stmt->execute();

echo json_encode("Done");
?>
```

The user that I'm using for the database connection only have the privilege to update the state column, therefore I don't see the risk for SQL injections. Am I right about this, and what's wrong with my code?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables alert](https://xkcd.com/327/).... never make assumptions and allow unvalidated input directly in your SQL statements

Comment: Considering OP asks whether SQL injection is still an issue with restricted permissions, that's a completely useless comment...

Comment: if you use `prepare` prepared statement, I would expect to see some placeholders in query string and some `bindParam` after prepare...

Answer (score 0):

As for the second part of your question...

> ...I don't see the risk for SQL injections. Am I right about this...

1. user permissions tend to change over time, and it's not always remembered what code utilizing those permissions needs to be updated.
2. just because you may not technically be obviously susceptible to SQL injection attacks, there's still problems that could lead to a deleterious experience for your end-users. Take for example, some day in the future a new `fetchCode` is added to your table that might contain a `'` character like `"9focuspoints's New Code"` which unescaped would break this, leading to frustrated customers and maybe even an undesired late night customer service call depending on the severity of the operation.

It's just poor form, and you've already gone through most of the syntactical work to actually prepare the statement, so you might as well finish the job.

---

As for the former part of your question, I am, and you should be too extremely suspicious of the changes surrounding the event:

> ...this code have been working previously but isn't anymore...

What has changed since this worked? If this code hasn't changed, then I doubt you're going to get much help posting it here. Some questions to check:

1. Does the SQL statement work when run in a stand-alone client?
2. When you `var_dump` your variables along the way troubleshooting, do they contain the values you expect?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to run it in a stand-alone client when I've got the opportunity. The strange part is that it nothing has changed since the code worked. I echoed out the query and all variables contain the correct values.